# Editing and commiting DataGridView cell changes (bound to a List of Objects)

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, .net-4.5

I have a Windows Forms application which contains a DataGridView inside it. The DataGridView gets populated from a DataSource which is a list of MyClass. MyClass contains a set of properties and a constructor like so:

```
public class MyClass
{    
    public PropertyA{get;set};
    public ProppertyB{get;set;}
    public ProppertyC{get;Set}
}
```

Then in the Main form I have a method which returns a List myCollection and a button which populates the DataGridView with "myCollection" like so:

```
private void btlLoadDataInDataGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                   
    var headers = GetAllHeaders();//GetAllheaders returns a List<MyClass>
    dataGridView1.DataSource = headers;
}
```

What I get is a DataGridView with the columns from the original MyClass.
 Now I want to be able to edit the data in the DataGridView and commit this change to the actual list of MyClass properties. Can somebody please advice what would be a best approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edit your grid whose `DataSource` is set to a List of objects and change any cell's value, the underlying data in the row is automatically updated. In your case the underlying row data is of type `MyClass`.

At any point of time you can get the updated row data, using the `DataGridView.DataBoundItem` property.

Sample code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    MyClass rowData = item.DataBoundItem as MyClass;
    if(rowData != null)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

The data commit logic is different when your grid is populated from a database. You have to write code to commit the changed data to the database.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you soo much. I ended up returning a collection of MyClass using the cast: `            var selected = from row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                           select (MyClass) row.DataBoundItem;`